# Где функция "Go to next breakpoint" в IDEA?

Tags: отладка, ide, java, intellij-idea, breakpoint

Доброго времени суток, Хэшкод.

Работаю вот с такой замечательной средой разработки, как IDEA(точнее портирую с Android-а приложение, чей исходный код просматриваю через нее) и малость офигеваю: куда добрые разработчики запрятали такую штуку, как "Continue" или "Go to the next breakpoint" в пошаговой отладке? Она вообще есть? Что-то гугл-запросы ничего мне не прояснили.

З.Ы. Некстати, это нормально для Java, что отладчик периодически пытается задуматься о вечном? Просто сам я обычно пишу на C# и использую Visual Studio и к таким перлам при дебаге не привык.

Comment: По поводу "задуматься о вечном", - это, возможно, срабатывает сборщик мусора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нажимайте на кнопочку, очень напоминающую "Play" в проигрывателе (диалог, который снизу появляется при отладке).

Comment: Тьфу, точно, не заметил Resume Program. :) Позор мне, позор.

Answer (score 2):

F6 - next step
F8 - next breakpoint

Ну или в там - в режиме дебага, появляется вкладка с процессами и на ней есть нужные кнопки

Comment: Да вот в том то и дело, что нет там такого. Есть Step Over - переход на след строку, Step Into - заход в метод и Step Out. И куча force DoSamethings.

Comment: может ты брекпоинты не расставил? )

Comment: Расставил, уже разобрался, см выше. Плюсанул к ответу, у меня просто странная невнимательность.